# How i can customize WordPress front page in WP dashboard editor?

Tags: editor, frontpage

Although there are many questions related to front end editing, still none of them provided me some way to deal up with customizing WordPress front page using WordPress dashboard editor.
I'll be glad if some one can guide me through WordPress core file functionality involved in setting up my front page; or in other words, setting up my WP Home page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Elementor](https://elementor.com/) plugin.

Elementor is quickly growing in popularity and is another impressive freemium page builder plugin for WordPress. With a good selection of widgets and page templates in the free version, Elementor is certainly competitive. So let’s find out if it should be your page builder plugin of choice.

Comment: I have used all among them, here I am asking about editing front page using WordPress core files.

Comment: First You must knowledge about html, css, javascript and php for edit the theme files. Then go to Host directory wp-content -> themes -> your theme then find index.php or front-page.php file for edit. For more details go [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)